# Refluxjs & React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

I am trying to use refluxjs with react functional components instead of classes. Does anybody have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like there is no support for it based on this comment in their issues tab: https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs/issues/554#issuecomment-735750175.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was looking all over the place for an example!